# Gerando páginas estáticas com Thymeleaf no Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, template, thymeleaf

Tenho diversos dados que chegam via JSON em um request e necessito injeta-los em um template html estático e retornar o arquivo ".html" no response ao usuário, para que ele consiga fazer o download do arquivo, sem que seja renderizada a página gerada.

Qual seria um caminho viável para implementar essa solução?

Comment: Eu não entendi bem. Você precisa gerar um html e enviar como download? É isso?

Comment: Isso! Preciso enviar o arquivo .html gerado e retornar isso pro usuário fazer o download.